# Class object (list) has odd behaviour

Tags: python, tkinter

I recently tinker with Tkinter and I decided to make some simple game. I choose classic snake like game. Everything goes good but I encountered odd behaviour of list, which is container for the snake object. I tried to programm the propagation of the subsequent snake segments and every single attempt has failed so far. The code is simple and straight forward, but in that case it simply does not work as it should.

The object self.snake_object looks like this. In its initial state.

```
    self.snake_object = [[312, 192, 1, 'left'],
                         [336, 192, 2, 'left'],
                         [360, 192, 3, 'left'],
                         [384, 192, 4, 'left']]
```

In other words.

```
    self.snake_object[[cord_x, cord_y, seg_num, label]]

    #Every segment of the snake is in list and those lists are contained in another list.
    #cord_x - coordinate x of corresponding segment.
    #cord_y - coordinate y of corresponding segment.
    #seg_num - number corresponding segment.
    #label - information where is forward of the segment.
```

This is the code.

```
    old_snake_object = self.snake_object
    new_snake_object = self.snake_object

    for s in range(0, len(old_snake_object)-1):
        if old_snake_object[s][3] != new_snake_object[s+1][3]:
            new_snake_object[s+1][3] = old_snake_object[s][3]

    self.snake_object = new_snake_object
```

This does not work even in more crude form.

```
    old_snake_object = self.snake_object
    new_snake_object = self.snake_object

    for s in range(0, len(old_snake_object)-1):
        if old_snake_object[s][3] == 'left':
            new_snake_object[s+1][3] = 'left'
        elif old_snake_object[s][3] == 'right':
            new_snake_object[s+1][3] = 'right'
        elif old_snake_object[s][3] == 'up':
            new_snake_object[s+1][3] = 'up'
        elif old_snake_object[s][3] == 'down':
            new_snake_object[s+1][3] = 'down'

    self.snake_object = new_snake_object
```

I could past whole code if you need it to help. Just write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer.
Indeed, there was a problem with copy of the list, in this case self.snake_object. The problem was that You are not able to copy items in list to new list, simply by writing the equal sign between those two lists. This method makes that this new list is only referring to given set of items in old list. That was clearly stated by Daniel and thanks for that.

There is simple proof for that.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b[0] = 4
>>> print(a)
[4, 2, 3]
```

But You are not able to copy list, by simply adding '[:]' on the end of the new list. It still makes only reference, to the old list.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b[0] = 4
>>> print(a)
[4, 2, 3]
```

The fastest way to copy things from one list to another is to `import copy` module and use of `copy.deepcopy()` method.

```
>>> import copy
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> b[0] = 4
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print(b)
[4, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not copy the list on assignments, they are only references. Make an explicit copy:

```
old_snake_object = self.snake_object
new_snake_object = self.snake_object[:]

for s in range(0, len(old_snake_object)-1):
    if old_snake_object[s][3] != new_snake_object[s+1][3]:
        new_snake_object[s+1][3] = old_snake_object[s][3]

self.snake_object = new_snake_object
```

Comment: It still does not work and shows the same odd behaviour. 'Labels' from the snake_object, are not overwritten in right sequence, but all at once and 'label' parameter is always taken from the first segment of the snake. In short version state [[up], [left], [left], [left]] becomes [[up], [up], [up], [up]] instead of [[up], [up], [left], [left]].